# How to run wukong examples?

Tags: ruby, hadoop

Wukong looks like a pretty nice Ruby way to get into Hadoop through the streaming interface. However, after looking over the examples at the git page:

https://github.com/infochimps-labs/wukong/tree/master/examples

I have no idea how to actually run any of these and generate output.

EDIT: I tried running the following example:

```
$ ./word_count.rb --run=local README.txt .
```

This generates an error:

```
/Users/evanzamir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- wukong/script (LoadError)
    from /Users/evanzamir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from ./word_count.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

It seems to be having an issue with the line `require 'wukong/script'`, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried [the instructions here](http://mrflip.github.io/wukong/usage.html)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting errors from that, but it answers the question. If someone wants to close this, that's fine with me.